# Duplicate result entries with find command

Tags: bash, shell, find, glob

Why do I get almost duplicate entries (starting with or without the starting point .) with the following command please:

```
find .  * -type f | grep '082235'
./Takeout-1/Google Photos/2017-12-07/20171207_082235.jpg.json
./Takeout-2/Google Photos/2017-12-07/20171207_082235.jpg
Takeout-1/Google Photos/2017-12-07/20171207_082235.jpg.json
Takeout-2/Google Photos/2017-12-07/20171207_082235.jpg
```

Is there a tweak/option with find to get rid of each duplicate?

Comment: I've just noticed that `find * -type f | grep '082235 ` does the job but don't know why...

Comment: Why not just `find . -type f | grep '082235'`?  `find .` is a lot safer than `find *`.

Comment: @codeforester you're totally right, `find . -type f | grep '082235'` is the good solution! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` command can take zero or more starting points, i.e., files or directories whose sub-directories will be searched.  Starting points can also be globs that the shell will expand, such as `*`, which is expanded to the list of all non-hidden files and directories in the current directory.  Find goes sequentially through its starting points, so it may output repeated files and/or directories if the files reachable through different starting points overlap.

The most trivial example is that, if you are in a directory that contains file `foo`,

```
$ find foo foo
```

will generate the following output:

```
foo
foo
```

By running the command `find . *` you are providing as starting points: first, the current directory, `.`; and second, all non-hidden files in that directory.  This will naturally create duplicated outputs: each regular file found with `.` as a starting point that is not a hidden file at the top level (i.e., `./.bar` files) and is not contained by a hidden directory at the top level (i.e., `./.baz/` directories) will also appear in the second part of the list without the leading `./`.

You probably just want to run

```
$ find . -type f
```

Note that, if you were running `find . *` not selecting regular files with the `-type f` condition, there would be an item not necessarily involving hidden files or directories that would only appear once: the `.` entry.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your use of `find .  *`. Saying that is effectively saying to search the current directory (which is recursive,  so including everything in it), then also specifying to search everything in it again separately. Use `find .` or `find *` instead. (Note that the latter will skip files in hidden directories.)